# Can someone please explain what a PT1 filter is in simple terms?

Tags: control-engineering, automotive-engineering

The context here is for determining how driveability filters are calibrated since most of them use pt1 filters to filter the torque demand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PT1 Filter without Derivative](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/pt1-filter-without-derivative)

Answer (score 2):

A PT1 filter works so that its output is always changing at a rate that would get it from its present value to a value equal to the input value in a certain time period.  This period is called the time constant for the filter.

If the input value is steady or moving slowly (relative to the time constant), then the output will be approximately equal to the input.

But, if, for example, the input suddenly jumps from 0 to 50 (a step input), and the time constant is, let's say, 10 seconds, then the output will start increasing from zero at a rate of 5 units per second (which would get it to 50 in 10 seconds if it kept going at that rate). After around 1 second the output will be 5. Now it will increase at 4.5 units per second (which would get it from 5 to 50 in 10 seconds).  After around 2 seconds the output will be 9.5. It will then be 41.5 away from the input value, so it will be increasing at 4.15 units per second.  The output will continue increasing in this manner, getting slower and slower as it gets closer and closer to the input value.  If the input remains steady at 50, then eventually the output will match it (mathematically you can say the output keeps getting closer to the input value without ever reaching it, but in the real world the difference between output and input will be so small that we can say they are equal).  The result is the sharp jump at the input is filtered to produce a more rounded curve at the output.

Now, what if the input jumped from zero to 50, and then dropped back to zero after 2 seconds?  As explained above, after around 2 seconds, the output is 9.5. After that it starts dropping again as the input has gone back to zero.  The result is the temporary spike at the input is filtered to produce a smaller bump at the output.

So you can see that the PT1 filter smoothes out sharp jumps and spikes. The higher the time constant, the higher the smoothing effect.

(Note that for simplicity I have described the rate being re-evaluated every second. In an analog system, the rate is constantly adapting based on the current input and output values. In a computerised system, the rate is re-calculated at whatever the scan cycle of the program is).